# Display cutsom post type from specific category

Tags: custom-post-type, wordpress

I'd like to display custom posts from specific category in Wordpress in custom page.
My code is:

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) ); ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<?php
$thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
$thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id,'thumbnail-size', true);
?>
```

I'd like to display post from "loze" category.

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

You can use `category_name` for this.  Amend your `WP_Query` as follows:

```
$loop = new WP_Query( 
    array( 
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'category_name' => 'loze',
        'posts_per_page' => -1 
    ) 
);
```

However, I would recommend using the category ID instead (referenced using `cat` instead of `category_name`) as it's future-proofed somewhat (you could change the name of the category).

There is lots of information on this in the [category section of the WordPress Codex for WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters).